# Fetch errors from APNS with PHP

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I use a self written script to send push notifications to APNS with PHP. In order to be able to process errors I use the extended format for the Push notifications and would like to fetch results from the stream:

```
   // $apns = a stream_socket_client connection
   $apnsMessage  = pack('CNNnH*', 1, $i, $pnDetails['expiration_time'], 32, $pnDetails['token']);
   $apnsMessage .= pack('n', strlen($pnDetails['payload']));
   $apnsMessage .= $pnDetails['payload'];
   fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

   // Check for errors
   $errorResponse = @fread($apns, 6)
   if ($errorResponse != FALSE) {
    $unpackedError = unpack('Ccommand/CstatusCode/Nidentifier', $errorResponse);
   }
```

I have seen a very similar practice in the apns-php project, however, in my case the script always waits indefinitely at the fread line because it tries to read data which is not there (Apple only sends a response if there was an error). I have looking for ways to tell if there is any new data to read from a TCP stream, however, I could find none and the stream callback methods available for HTTP calls are not available for "raw" TCP connections either.

How can I transform my script to make sure it only calls fread when there actually is data to read? How does the apns-php project solve this issue (from what I could tell they were just calling fread as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the final hint came from Erwin. The trick was to deactivate the blocking with stream_set_blocking, now I just need to wait some time before fetching the results with fread to make sure that Apple has enough time to respond.

Comment: Could you please update the post with your solution? Thank you.

Comment: `stream_set_blocking($this->socketName, 0);`

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. Added this line right after connecting, but it still hangs on fread..

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to the right host `ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196` ?

They are using the following calls to connect and read data:

`stream_context_create` -> `stream_socket_client` -> `stream_set_blocking` (0) -> `stream_set_write_buffer` (0) -> `while (!feof($socket)) {}` -> `fread` (8192) -> `stream_select` (with timeout)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I am not talking about the feedback service, I am talking about the immediate error returned if the Push notification is malformed. See the error documentation with the extended format here: http://bit.ly/f1kvv1